# Use spinner as a menu in multiple activities

Tags: java, android, spinner

my question is the following: I have a spinner which acts as a menu in my mainactivity, i also want to use the same spinner in my other activities, so i can save some code lines. how can i achieve that? i will post the code, or is there a better solution to do this?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.comboCasino);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.comboCasino, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // this will be called when you select any item in this spinner
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // get the text at that position
                String Text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(Text.equals("Wien Simmering")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this,Simmering.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Wien Lugner City")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, LugnerCity.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Gmunden")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Gmunden.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Salzburg")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Salzburg.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Linz")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Linz.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Saalbach")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Saalbach.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Innsbruck")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Innsbruck.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Reutte")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Reutte.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Bregenz")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Bregenz.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Kufstein")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Kufstein.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
                if(Text.equals("Bratislava")) {
                    Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Bratislava.class);
                    startActivity(NewPost);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            }
        });
    }
```

here the xml

```
 <string-array name="comboCasino">
        <item>Filiale</item>
        <item>Wien Simmering</item>
        <item>Wien Lugner City</item>
        <item>Gmunden</item>
        <item>Salzburg</item>
        <item>Linz</item>
        <item>Saalbach</item>
        <item>Innsbruck</item>
        <item>Reutte</item>
        <item>Bregenz</item>
        <item>Kufstein</item>
        <item>Bratislava</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several potential solutions:

1. Add your spinner to the `ActionBar`.
2. Create a base class for all of your activities. This base class contains the intialization code for the `Spinner`.
3. Create a custom component with the appropriate logic. Add this component to each activity that needs the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You have it right. The actual initialization isn't that bad, as you're only declaring the `Spinner`, making the adapter, and applying the xml attributes (which aren't always needed if you make them with code), and then you give it an adapter. Your problem is the lengthy code in the `OnItemSelectedListener`.

You have the initialization right, I would just change your `if`s to a `switch` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.comboCasino);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.comboCasino, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    // this will be called when you select any item in this spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // get the text at that position
            String Text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, Simmering.class);
                        startActivity(NewPost);
                    case 1:
                        Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, LugnerCity.class);
                        startActivity(NewPost);
                    case 2:
                        Intent NewPost = new Intent(StartingPoint.this, WhateverTown.class);
                        startActivity(NewPost);
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    case 10:
                        ...........
                        ......
                } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    });
}
```

The int automatically passed to the `OnItemSelectedListener` called `position` marks the position on the list that was clicked, so you can use this instead of many `if`-statements.

Comment: thank you very much guys, first i will usw the switch case for the spinner. and second, i want to use the spinner in a base class, could you please tell me how i do this, and how do i implement this in my other activities? thank you in advance.

Comment: can somebody please tell me how i can create my spinner in a base class and implement it in all my other activities?

Comment: plus: i also would like the same ActionBar in all the other activities, i would be very happy if someone could help me to achieve this! thank you in advance

Comment: i yesterday tried your (Zolnoor) version which i myself found better but i had to add "{ }"'s and break;'s